# Mangling of symbol in object file and library

Tags: c++, stl, android-ndk, webrtc, std

I built a library for Android (WebRTC) and I'm now trying to build a sample file (main.cpp) using a function from that library. The compilation step seems to be ok, but during link I get this:

```
main.o:main.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'webrtc::CreateSessionDescription(std::string const&, std::string const&, webrtc::SdpParseError*)'
```

I therefore checked the undefined symbol in my main.o, and I see:

```
_ZN6webrtc24CreateSessionDescriptionERKSsS1_PNS_13SdpParseErrorE
```

while in the static library I see:

```
 _ZN6webrtc24CreateSessionDescriptionERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEES8_PNS_13SdpParseErrorE
```

I'm using the same NDK for both the builds, but I'm not sure what android version of the SDK WebRTC uses (I'm linking to the libs in platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib).

I also tried to demangle and my main.o contains:

```
U webrtc::CreateSessionDescription(std::string const&, std::string const&, webrtc::SdpParseError*)
```

while the library contains:

```
T webrtc::CreateSessionDescription(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, webrtc::SdpParseError*)
```

Any idea why this happens and how I can avoid it? Maybe using two different versions of the string header?

Comment: What C++ library implementation are you using? Please post your build.gradle and Android.mk (if you use it).

Comment: Yes, I suspect WebRTC is using libc++ and I'm using libstdc++. I'm using Qt for Android to build, and I see the command line is including ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include. I'm wondering if there is any way to make these two coexist...

Comment: How are you building WebRTC? It's easy enough to confirm what library it's building with by looking at the link line.

Comment: I don't see the build commands, but it is probably clang/libc++. And this is not probably what Qt expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was indeed that the library is built using libc++. Rebuilding on libstdc++ made the link suceed.